# NET Core 2 default 'Web Application" fails on remote IIS under win7

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

Built a default Net Core 2 app w/no authorization and successfully web-deployed via VS2017 Publish to remote IIS instance under Win 7. However, the app fails to run, generating an HTTP 500 error.

Log file shows a 500.19 error:

> Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port
>   cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status
>   time-taken 2018-03-29 20:42:20 ::1 GET / - 81 - ::1
>   Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko
>   500 19 5 296

After researching, there seems to be a myriad of options for setting up to run under IIS. I first tried MS [recommendations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?tabs=aspnetcore2x), which resulted in above error.

Here is web.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" 
           path="*" verb="*" 
           modules="AspNetCoreModule" 
           resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" 
                arguments=".\WebApplication1.dll" 
                stdoutLogEnabled="true" 
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is IIS site configuration:

[image]

IIS add-ins:

1. MS Web Platform Installer
2. Net Core Server Hosting
3. Web Deploy
4. MS .NET Core 2.0.6 Windows Server Hosting

Questions:

1. should a default app work as is when published to IIS?
2. If not, what is necessary?

Comment: When you checked the event log (with `Event Viewer`) was there anything interesting there?

Comment: Did you install the .NET Core Server Hosting Bundle? It won't work with an OOB IIS

Comment: Yes, bundle is installed. See above to see installed packages.

Comment: The actual 500.19 page would tell what is the cause. Try every way to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was adding IIS Application Pool access rights to the folder holding the Net Core app as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) in the Microsoft documentation.

So, yes, a default ASP.NET Core 2 app will run fine under IIS as is. Problem had nothing do with application at all.

Since this problem cost me almost three days of my life due to ignorance of web development and IIS specifically, I will post this answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Thank you Simonare for sending me down the right track, albeit indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

This doesnt show enough information about error.

First thing first I suggest you to enable stdoutLog under web.config. And It also make sense to enable detailed error logs under program.cs by including 
`UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
CaptureStartupErrors(true)`

```
var host =  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
        .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

furthermore you can try to run dotnetcore application on server by opening command prompt on the deployment directory and running application with executing `dotnet yourApplicatonName.dll

further troubleshooting information can be found below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/troubleshoot

EDIT: When you publish your application it sometimes need to publish your application by targetting remote operation system version. For this you need to include `RuntimeIdenfiers` in your project.csproj

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

Catalog of the runtime identifiers can be found in
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

then you need to update your publish profile to target remote platform correcly. By Default, It is "Portable"

Comment: Thanks for help. Should a default generated web application be expected to run under IIS or are changes needed?

Comment: You do not need change But you need to install .NET Core Runtime packages (2 package) under https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/Windows/run

Comment: .NET Core 2.0.6 runtime and Windows Server Hosting both installed. Is more needed?

Comment: No. please follow the troubleshooting routine which I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, Simonare. Turned out to be a folder permissions issue and nothing to due with the app per se.